# How to find the Delivery Date Selected While Checkout?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, sales-order, additional-information

We are using **Firecheckout**. There's an option to choose Delivery Date while checkout but How can we find the Customer selected delivery date in "Order View" from website admin?

Comment: I invite you to contact its developer as it is unlikely you'll get a response here for a paid extension.